# Find $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin\left(1-\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)}{x^2}$. Is my approach correct?

Tags: limits, trigonometry

Find:
$$
L = \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin\left(1-\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)}{x^2}
$$

My approach:

Because of the fact that the above limit is evaluated as $\frac{0}{0}$, we might want to try the De L' Hospital rule, but that would lead to a more complex limit which is also of the form $\frac{0}{0}$.

What I tried is:
$$
L = \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin\left(1-\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)}{1-\frac{\sin(x)}{x}}\frac{1}{x^2}\left(1-\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)
$$
Then, if the limits
$$
L_1 = \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin\left(1-\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)}{1-\frac{\sin(x)}{x}},
$$

$$
L_2 = \lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{x^2}\left(1-\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)
$$
exist, then $L=L_1L_2$.

For the first one, by making the substitution $u=1-\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$, we have
$$
L_1 = \lim_{u\to u_0}\frac{\sin(u)}{u},
$$
where
$$
u_0 = \lim_{x\to0}\left(1-\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)=0.
$$
Consequently,
$$
L_1 = \lim_{u\to0}\frac{\sin(u)}{u}=1.
$$

Moreover, for the second limit, we apply the De L' Hospital rule twice and we find $L_2=\frac{1}{6}$.

Finally, $L=1\frac{1}{6}=\frac{1}{6}$.

Is this correct?

Comment: The answer is right. The $1/6$ is clear from the power series expansion of $\frac{\sin x}{x}$.

Comment: Thank you very much @AndréNicolas!

Comment: You are welcome. That was a nice trick, multiplying and dividing by $1-\frac{\sin x}{x}$. Using L'Hospital's Rule afterwards is OK, but in general when possible I get a better feel of what's happening from the power series than from L'Hospital's Rule.

Comment: Better to do $L_2$ as the limit of $\frac{x-\sin x}{x^3}$, which requires L'Hopital three times. You might have to apply some additional knowledge your way.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, the power series trick is really nice (I wasn't aware of that). Actually, this is a question of the exams I took today in order to get approved to the faculty of Mathematics of the university of my city.

Comment: Good luck on the entrance process. You showed creativity on this question.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, I truly appreciate your kind words! Thanks a lot again!

Comment: Cleverly done !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*In a slightly different way*, using the Taylor expansion, as $x \to 0$,
$$
\sin x=x-\frac{x^3}6+O(x^5)
$$ gives
$$
1-\frac{\sin x}x=\frac{x^2}6+O(x^4)
$$ then
$$
\sin \left( 1-\frac{\sin x}x\right)=\frac{x^2}6+O(x^4)
$$ and

> $$
> \frac{\sin \left( 1-\frac{\sin x}x\right)}{x^2}=\frac16+O(x^2)
> $$

from which one may conclude easily.

Answer (score 2):

**By L' Hospital anyway**:

$$\frac{\sin\left(1-\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)}{x^2}$$ yields

$$\cos\left(1-\frac{\sin(x)}x\right)\frac{\sin(x)-x\cos(x)}{2x^3}.$$

The first factor has limit $1$ and can be ignored.

Then with L'Hospital again:

$$\frac{x\sin(x)}{6x^2},$$

which clearly tends to $\dfrac16$.

Comment: Wasn't so horrible after all.